# How can I learn TCP/IP and socket programming using .NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Where could I find good resources and examples for learning how to utilize TCP/IP in .NET/C# 2.0?  Any suggestions on where to start?  I'm pretty new at socket programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the new MSDN site is really nice, and cleanly separates the different language examples.  Anyhow, you'll likely start with [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=VS.71).aspx) and [TcpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=VS.71).aspx).  I played with the .NET sockets library for the first time last week, and was able to get a TCP command interpreter implemented very, very quickly.

Comment: MSDN kind of got a bad rap during the MFC days, but I've found for .NET it simply is the best place to go for looking at code snippets and documentation.  However don't use their internal search, it still sucks.  However a google search will usually find the MSDN reference page very quickly.

Comment: @Justin: well, I used to feel the same way.  I would just use a search like `tcpclient site:microsoft.com` in the chrome address bar and it would get me the right page.  However, with the new site, I've found that the search works pretty well for me.

Comment: Hitting F1 in Visual Studio in 2012 really good too now - click on a type in the editor and click F1 and it opens the MSDN online documentation in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

[Distributed .NET Programming in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590590392) - Tom Barnaby

A book may not be what you wanted to hear about, but it is by far the best reference I have come across yet. It covers everything from .NET Remoting, Threading, and lower level Networking.